# Which rational functions are derivatives of rational functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integration, derivatives, rational-functions

I thought it was interesting that $\frac{u^2+1}{(u^2-2u-1)^2}$ has the very simple integral $-\frac{u}{u^2-2u-1}$ but both of $\frac{u^2}{(u^2-2u-1)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(u^2-2u-1)^2}$ are very complicated (the transcendental parts cancel each other though).

So my question is how do I check by looking at a rational function whether or not it's a derivative of a rational function?

For example $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ isn't but $\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ is. How can we tell in general?

Comment: Could this be related to checking if the recurrence relations associated to the generating function satisfy $n|a_n$?

Comment: Consider the partial fractions decomposition of a rational function. What kind of terms have rational primitives? And which ones don't?

Comment: See here, over the reals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions

Comment: @julien, thank you but does applying partial fractions reduce the problem to something simpler? I can't see it

Comment: Yes, there are only finitely many cases to consider then. For instance, as soon as the decomposition involves $1/(x-\alpha)$, your primitive has some $\ln|1-\alpha|$ and it's not gonna be rational. Likewise, if there is some $1/(x^2+a^2)$ ($a\neq 0$), there will be some $\arctan (x/a)$ and the primitive will not be rational.

Comment: I like this idea but what if two different partial fractions have rational and trancendental parts, but the trancendental prats cancel? also I don't see how it's finitely many cases, each partial fraction will be a lower degree poly divided by a power of an irreducible.

Comment: Actually when I do partial fractions on (u^2+1)/(u^2-2u-1) both of the partial fractions have transcendental parts.. which do cancel to give a rational function. So I don't think we can use partial fractions.. unless we know how to check for cancelling.

Comment: Here is the decomposition I found: $1+(1+\sqrt{2})/(u-1-\sqrt{2})+(1-\sqrt{2})/(u-1+\sqrt{2})$. Hence the primitives are $u+(1+\sqrt{2})\ln|u-1-\sqrt{2}|+(1-\sqrt{2})\ln|u-1+\sqrt{2}|+C$. Did you find this too? If so, how do you simplify this to a rational function?

Comment: @julien, i'm very sorry I meant to write (u^2+1)/(u^2-2u-1)^2 in my previous comment. For partial fractions of that I got $\frac{2(u+1)}{(u^2-2u-1)^2} + \frac{1}{u^2-2u-1}$ and both of these have transcendental integrals.

Comment: Well, for this one, your decomposition is not over since $(u^2-2u-1)=(u-1-\sqrt{2})(u-1+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: For the record. I suggested an edit replacing the tag "algebra-precalculus" with the tag "calculus", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1999386).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examine the poles of your function (in the complex plane).  If all residues are zero, you are in good shape.

Comment: thank you very much. is this an if and only if condition?

Comment: Of course.  You will learn about this when you study complex analysis.

Answer (score 3):

To make a little more clear the reason why GEdgar's solution is works, observe that since all polynomials factor over $\mathbb{C}$, you can take the rational function $r$ and expand it completely using the method of partial fractions.

That is, if $r$ has poles at $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_k$ with multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_k$ respectively, then for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, and each $j\in\{1,\ldots,m_i\}$, there is are constants $a_{ij}$ such that the following holds.

$$r(z)=\dfrac{a_{11}}{z-z_1}+\dfrac{a_{12}}{(z-z_1)^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_{1m_1}}{(z-z_1)^{m_1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_{k1}}{z-z_k}+\dfrac{a_{k2}}{(z-z_k)^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_{km_k}}{(z-z_k)^{m_k}}.$$

Every term here is integrable, except the terms $\dfrac{a_{i1}}{z-z_1}$ where $a_{i1}\neq0$.  This $a_{i1}$ is exactly the residue of the function at $z_i$.  Therefore we get the criterion described by GEdgar.

Answer (score 1):

For your last example, it is easy to see that a) you have a simple factor of $x$ in the numerator, and b) your denominator is a simple power of $1+x^2$.  The integral is easily transformed into the form $\int du/(1+u)^2$, which is a rational function.  This works for any power of $1+x^2$ greater than 1.