# Use Mittag-Leffler to prove Weierstrass Factorization Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Use the Mittag-Leffler theorem to prove the following:  Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in a simply connected domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ that does not have an accumulation point in $D$.  Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $f$ so that its zero set equals $(a_n)$ counting multiplicity.

In particular, do not use the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem, Weierstrass Products, or Blaschke Products in your answer.

I have no idea how to do this problem.  Can someone help?

Comment: Do you know what the Mittag-Leffler theorem says?

Comment: The Mittag-Leffler theorem says that it is possible to construct a meromorphic function with the poles and singular parts of your choosing.

Comment: that doesn't give the existence of a function with zeros at $(a_n)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Idea:* If $f(a) = 0$ with multiplicity $k$ then the logarithmic
derivative $(\log f)' = f'/f$ satisfies
$$
  \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{k}{z-a} + O(1) \quad \text{ for } z \to  a \, .
$$

---

Use the Mittag-Leffler theorem to construct a meromorphic function $g$
in $D$ with poles exactly at the points $a_n$ and principal parts
$$
   \frac{k_n}{z-a_n}
$$ 
where $k_n$ is the desired multiplicity at $a_n$.

Then show that there is a holomorphic function $f$ in $D$ such that
$$ \frac{f'}{f} = g \, ,$$ details can be found for example in [Which meromorphic functions are logarithmic derivatives of other meromorphic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660732/which-meromorphic-functions-are-logarithmic-derivatives-of-other-meromorphic-fun).

$f$ has zeros exactly at the points $a_n$ with multiplicity $k_n$.

Comment: Doesn't the link you provide only show that $f$ is guaranteed to be meromorphic, not necessarily entire?

Comment: @TonyS.F.: Here all  $k_n$ are positive , therefore $f$ is entire. If $k_n \in \Bbb Z$ then $f$ can be meromorphic.